# Regular Expression in Java Script

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not able to understand this pattern. What does this Regex mean?

```
/([^0-9])\d{1,4}([^0-9])/g
```

Comment: Which part is causing you trouble?

Comment: Use [RegEx101](http://regex101.com). Paste the expression there in the input box and it will give the description below.

Comment: Do you understand regular expressions and just stuck with particular part of this expression or just asking us say you what that means without trying to understand it by yourself? The second case is not good, if so.

Comment: Actually I am new to regexp

Comment: I understand that ([^0-9]) means no digits in the pattern rest I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 4):

This regex will:

```
/           /* delimeter */
([^0-9])    /* capture non-digit character */
\d{1,4}     /* match 1 to 4 digits */
([^0-9])    /* capture 1 non-digit character */
/g          /* multiple times in the string */
```

PS:  `[^0-9]` is identical to `[^\d]` also identical to `\D`

Answer (score 1):

It's matching a String which contains the following:

- some character which is not a digit
- followed by 1 to 4 digits
- followed by a character which is not a digit